# Eclipse deleting .history folders

Tags: java, eclipse

I've noticed the .history folder in my Eclipse IDE .plugins folder is building up:

C:\QuestEclipseIDE.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.history

Am I able to purge or otherwise reduce the number of these folders? Is there an auto-purge setting or do I have to manually prune these down?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where Eclipse stores the [Local History](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_is_the_workspace_local_history_stored%3F).

Look at `Preferences > General > Workspace > Local History` to configure.

"Preferences" is in the Windows menu on Linux and Windows. On macOS it is in the "Eclipse" menu and is called "Settings" on newer versions of macOS.

Comment: The actual question was not answered: Is it safe to delete the .history folder or not?

Comment: @Lonzak No it is not safe, use the local history configuration to control the folder. Despite what some answers on Stack Overflow might say it is almost never safe to delete anything in the .metadata folders.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is your local history (it tracks edits you make to source files.) You can [modify retention settings](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-14.htm?cp=0_4_1_35) through the Preferences.